# Meaning of `<==>` in documentation?

Tags: notation

Title says it all. I just need to confirm that...
`X.__add__(y) <==> x+y`
...doesn't mean anything more than just 'same as'

The problem is Google returns zero results when you search for `<==>`

Comment: Can you at least provide a link to a page which uses this notation?

Comment: `<===>` is not standard notation, so it is impossible to tell. Use your common sense.

Comment: It's hard to tell without context; please give a link to where you found this.

Comment: This is *probably* an attempt to write "$\iff$" using ASCII symbols. It means "if and only if" in the sense of formal logics, that is "$A \iff B$" translates to "whenever $A$ is true, then $B$ is well, and vice cersa".

It seems to have been misused there, though. You don't give a source, but they seems to be wanting to express either "define `X.__add__(y)` to mean `x+y`" or "`X.__add__(y)` is equivalent to `x+y`". The latter seems to match the logical operator on a superficial, English-language level, but they equivalent things are not truth values here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means "logically equivalent to".